# Windows Phone 8 App Font Color Issue

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have created a Windows Phone App that is high on graphics. I have set the colors for better viewing, mostly of dark colors. So as expected, the font colors of my text blocks are bright colors for better visibility. I am using Visual Studio Professional 2012. C# and XAML.

Unfortunately, if the user has a theme of light set on their device, my font colors change to black, which greatly affect their visibility. I am aware that the app gets static phone resources but I have no idea how to change that.

Comment: If you are going to modify the color scheme in any way you need to account for the different possible color outcomes. You will need to go through all UI Controls and set the colors how you want them to be viewed. Otherwise you are going to continue to have these issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll just need to override the default colors for stuff like that which there's multiple tutorials and resources available on the web to get you started like [this one](http://www.markermetro.com/2012/07/technical/windows-8-overriding-metro-app-resources/).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to set the proberty of the textbox or block to automatic

Comment: An "automatic" property? Can you please explain? I may learn something new here.

Comment: FontColor = Auto, when the theme is dark, the font is automaticaly set to white, and vice versa